# Is Real Projective N-space, RPN, contractible?

Tags: general-topology

I am able to identify a needed contractible sub-manifold of RPN. I wish to claim that RPN itself is not contractible for finite N. I don't know how to verify that conjecture, nor have I been able to find an assertion one way or the other in the literature.

Comment: $S^n$ is a nontrivial covering space of $\mathbb{RP}^n$ for $n >1$.

Comment: You can calculate its [homotopy and homology groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_space#Algebraic_topology_of_real_projective_spaces) to see that $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is not contractible for any $n\geq1$.